# Symfony 4 - Cannot create an instance of DateTime from serialized data

Tags: serialization, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I want to persist some Json data in a entity with Symfony 4.3.
As example, I usually do this :

```
public function storeMetadata(EncoderInterface $encoders, ObjectNormalizer $normalizers, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{

  $data = [
      'url' => 'www.google.com',
      'title' => 'Nice title',
      'created' => '2019-12-15 11:40:00'
  ];

  $data = json_encode($data);

  $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizers], [$encoders]);
  $documentMetadata = $serializer->deserialize($data, DocumentMetadata::class, 'json');

  $entityManager->persist($documentMetadata);
  $entityManager->flush();
}
```

But, because I have a datetime field, I got an error "Cannot create an instance of DateTime from serialized data because its constructor requires parameter "time" to be present."

I understand that my date is a string and it should be a datetime object, but how can I serialize this date? Thanks!

**My Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $created;

public function getCreated(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
  return $this->created;
}

public function setCreated(?\DateTimeInterface $created): self
{
   $this->created = $created;

   return $this;
}
```

Comment: Did you fix this? I have a similar issue.

Comment: Yes, with DateTimeNormalizer.

Comment: $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, null, null, new ReflectionExtractor());
$serializer = new Serializer([new DateTimeNormalizer(), $normalizer]);